# string.find fails with a hyphen

Tags: string, lua

I started [making Factorio mods](https://mods.factorio.com/user/AivanF) with Lua, and a funny problem appeared: I cannot correctly perform a simple substring search in Lua. `string.find` can correctly find "-mining-" or "-drones", but not both words with a hyphen. How to fix this??

```lua
local str = "copper-ore-mining-drone-10"
local sub = "mining-drone"
print(str:find(sub))
```

For quick testing:
https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Maybe `find` uses some pattern syntax and a hyphen isn't used literally? But I found nothing about it [in the docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html), and trying to escape it -" leads to `invalid escape sequence` error. In case it requires some escaping, how can I do this automatically? Cuz I receive substring value from an external source.

Comment: You should escape it `mining%-drone`

Comment: @shingo well, and what if I get a substring from other place? I should perform a substring replace on a substring?  But it won't work with this special character 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more googling, I found that yeah, `find` method really uses some expression syntax (strange that it's not explain in the docs). There is a couple of solutions:

#### 1. Use escape symbol `%`

Seems like lua's search expression syntax uses `%` as an escape character:

```lua
str:find("mining%-drone")
```

#### 2. Set `plain` flag

The method has some arguments that also aren't mention in the docs, the third one is `plain` flag which allows to treat a substring literally:

```lua
str:find(sub, 1, true)
```

Comment: [Patterns are explained in the docs.](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1)

Comment: @Luatic I understand that is has to be explained somewhere, but it's strange it's not even referenced in the "Pattern-Matching Functions" chapter which is googled by `lua string find` query.

Comment: You said that find's args are not mentioned in "the docs" which doesn't make any sense it is right in the reference manual [string.find](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.find)